# Can't understand a notation regarding weak solution of Vlasov-Poisson system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The text is from https://cmouhot.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/chapter5.pdf .

In section 1, it uses  $~f_t~$ to represent a smooth solution of Vlasov-Poisson system (VPS). I think here $~t~$ in $~f_t~$ as subscript doesn't mean $~f_t(t,x,v)~$ as a function with $~t~$ fixed, because the solution should be a function with respect to $~t~$ and $~t~$ shouldn't be fixed.

But in section 4, definition 4.30, weak solution is defined as a family $~(f_t)_{t\in[0,T]}~$. I think here $~t~$ as a subscript certainly means time, i.e. $~f_t~$ has a fixed time $~t~$.

So, what does $~f_t~$ mean?

And after a lot of Google searches, I want to know is there any other good material (like textbooks with detailed infomation) regarding this topic--weak solution of VPS or relativistic VPS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that $f_t\equiv f(t)$ in this context. As for more details on the vlasov system, what about [Dolbeault's paper](http://www.aimsciences.org/journals/displayArticles.jsp?paperID=291), [Perthame's paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-02/S0273-0979-04-01004-3/), or the books of [Glassey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713676), [Cercignani](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781489954114), [Cercignani-Illner-Pulvirenti](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387942940). You can also find a lot of material in [Mouhot-Villani's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2760).

Comment: Thank you for your time, though it's not that helpful.

Comment: @coderfive What are looking for exactly? Are the above references too specific? Do you need a reference for modern methods on pdes? Or something more specific on kinetic equations?

Comment: It's just that life hasn't been kind to me recently. I'm an undergrad, and I need to finish this paper in 10 days or I can't graduate. Besides, there're other things over which I have no control and that take a lot of time.  Thanks anyway. It's very kind of you.